# Devise with Google OmniAuth not loading client_id in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth

My rails site loads the correct request in development, but in production the client_id is empty in my OAuth request.

```
access_type=offline
client_id=
redirect_uri=https://example.com/accounts/auth/google_oauth2/callback
response_type=code
scope=email profile
state=...valid state here
```

My client ID is loaded in `config\initializers\devise.rb'`

```
 config.omniauth :google_oauth2, 
      Rails.application.credentials.google_omniauth_provider_key,
      Rails.application.credentials.google_omniauth_provider_secret
```

The value is loaded correctly in in `rails c -e production` when I load the console and test `Rails.application.credentials.google_omniauth_provider_key`

My logs don't show any errors or any other hint of what might be wrong. I made sure that my ENV-variable GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID is defined.

Answer (score 0):

I just removed the 12 factor gem and this works now. I would love to know how the 12factor gem and devise might be connected. I was moving my site from heroku to my own server.